# About c++11 range for loops and iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, syntax

What does the `c++11` range for loops do that cause this:

```
std::list<Point> item;
....
//fill the list somewhere else
....
for(Point p : item) {
    p.lowerY();
}
```

To work only one time (that is `lowerY()` does what it's supposed to do only once but the next time this loop is reached, it doesn't do anything), but this:

```
list<Point>::iterator it;
for (it = item.begin();it != item.end();++it) {
    it->lowerY();
}
```

Works perfectly every time. What's the difference?

Comment: I think.. it is because you are getting `p` by value (so.. if `lowerY` is supposed to change something on the original Point.. it will not affect the original). Try using `Point& p`.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, I see, so it made a copy of the original and changed that. @wendelbsilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your former code, the line

```
for(Point p : item) {
```

creates copies of the point every time you access the next item. To make sure that your calling of method lowerY() works, you need to redefine it as

```
for(Point & p : item) {
```

Comment: As a further note, you can would have the same problem with `for (auto p : item) {...}` because that works out to be `for (Point p : item) {}`, so you would want to use `for (auto &p : item) {...}` instead.